# Docker route traffic through vpn

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, vpn, docker-registry

I am trying to dockerize my existing application which is having the following stack

- Python (Flask)
- Microsoft SQL server
- Celery
- Redis

Following are the relevant files

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /opt/myapp

COPY myapp .
RUN pip install flask
RUN pip install --no-cache -r requirements/requirements.txt
```

**docker-compose.yml***

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python run.py
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

SQL server is not running as a docker container and it requires a VPN connection. Connection is being made from the code files itself. How can i connect to a non dockerized MS SQL running on some other server (need to be accessed with VPN) with dockerized application.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, especially for development is to use Docker's [host networking mode](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/):

```
docker run --network host [image]
```

This bypasses Docker's network isolation and will use the underlying host routing for the container.